# CodeIgniter 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, codeigniter

**ANSWERED! IT WAS A TYPO OMG. Always check EVERY CHARACTER**

I have three controllers, `Site`, `Login` and `Admin`. Site and Login work perfectly. I know I am logging in correctly, because I set the "incorrect username" blah blah error message, which shows up if I have incorrect login details. When I log in successfully however, I get a 500 Internal Server Error:

`HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request.`

Here's the admin controller:

```
function __construct()
    {
        parent::Controller();
        $this->isLogged();
    }

    function isLogged()
    {
        $isLogged = $this->session->userdata('isLogged');

        if (!isset($isLogged) || $isLogged != true)
        {
            redirect('login/index');
        }
    }

    function index()
    {
        $data['metaDescription'] = 'Admin area of danaemc.com';
        $data['keywords'] = '';
        $data['title'] = 'danaemc :: admin :: home';

        $data['main_content'] = 'admin_view';
        $this->load_view('includes/admin_template', $data);
    }
```

In which where it tries to access `index()`, the 500 error happens.

If you need more code, let me know in a comment. I hope it is something obvious.

Comment: Have you turned on logging in CodeIgniter and have you checked what's in the logfile? And in your webservers logfile (error_log)?

Comment: Thanks for the tip, thought I could only get server error logs (which I don't have access to to enable anyway). Here:

Comment: `ERROR - 2011-07-26 00:27:37 --> 404 Page Not Found --> favicon_ico`

Comment: Ugh, enter posts the comment! Anyway, I don't have any sort of resource, bar the actual favicon.ico which is there, and not even called to in the Admin section. It works fine in the public view.

Comment: Also, file permissions. at least change the file permission to at the very least "chmod 655". Had no problems in my windows machine and shared hosting, until I tried it out on my ubuntu box.(had to turn on display_errors in the php.ini in ubuntu)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a problem with your function that checks login. From the code you provide, I see this workflow:

- User is not logged: he's redirected to login/index and logs in.
- I suppose then he's redirected to admin controller, right? (when succesfully logged). Ok, now when admin controller is initialized it checks, within the controller itself, if the user is logged.
- It is, ok, but you don't tell it to go to some other page if the user is logged, so: you go to admin/index, but the constructor "intercepts" your request BEFORE it being routed (since the constructor is called as soon as the class is initialized, before the index() method is ever reached), and it hangs there: index() is called from the URL but the request doesn't go past isLogged(), and this discrepancy can cause you those troubles (I had a similar problem once).

You should do like this instead of using a controller's method:

```
function __construct()
{
       parent::__construct();   //what is parent::Controller() you wrote??
      if(!isset($this->session->userdata('isLogged')) OR $this->session->userdata('isLogged') == FALSE)
      {
         redirect('login', 'refresh'); // 'login/index' should be automatically called
      }

}
```

Moreover, as a side note, I'd do this check in some method in a library, and have it just return TRUE/FALSE and use that in my controller's constructor. Like

```
 function __construct()
 {
   parent::__construct();
   if(FALSE === $this->myauthlibrary->is_logged())
   {
     redirect('login','refresh');
   }
 }
```

This just for the sake of business logic and encapsulation, but it's just an idea and an advice.
If you still want to use the isLogged() of your Controller (but in this way every controller that checks for login needs is own method...) just put an ELSE clause, that redirects to index() if the checking gives positive response.

**Edited after comment:**

By chance are you calling a favicon in your meta tags?  `<link rel="icon" href="http://mysite/assets/favicon.ico" />` or whatever url you have? Did you spelled it RIGHT? And don't have a `href="http://mysite/favicon_ico"`, which CI things is a controller?

Comment: Okay, I've gone through the two answers thoroughly and edited my code so it temporarily has no authentication. Still get a 500 error...and still getting those weird `ERROR - 2011-07-26 05:53:21 --> 404 Page Not Found --> favicon_ico` errors.

Comment: @Danae updated my answer as per your last comment

Comment: It's not in the admin_view, but in the site_view it is:
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/images/assets/favicon.ico" />` Maybe base_url() stuffs it up...

Comment: @Danae View page source and see what path is written in your html... That `favicon_ico` error is puzzling

Comment: In the **public view** site, the link renders as `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/images/assets/favicon.ico" /> `.

Here's what I am seeing, note that the source code is **blank**:  
http://i.imgur.com/mL90w.png  Which is the admin view.

Comment: your base_url() looks like it's not echoing, have you correctly loaded the html helper? If you havent already, put it in the autoloader for a test

Comment: Already autoloaded. What confuses me the most is that the `site` controller that controls the public view works perfectly. URL, Form, form_validation, session...it's all fine. But not when it tries to render the admin_controller. But here's the echo:  
`<link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>/images/assets/favicon.ico" />`

Comment: Maybe try posting how you redirect to the admin controller (which is `Admin_controller extends CI_Controller`, right?). Also, maybe it's a typo you wrote here, but `$this->load_view('includes/admin_template', $data);` is misspelled

Comment: You're not going to believe this - **it was that typo**. Oh my. Thank you ever so much for all the help; I now also have a better understanding of redirect logic in general! Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You have an infinite redirect loop.

`isLogged()` is run in `__construct()` before `index()`, so it keeps redirecting as long as your session data isn't met.

Another thing: `!isset($isLogged)` will *always* return false, because `$this->session->userdata()` will return boolean `FALSE` if there is no value, which *is* set. Make sense?

`$this->session->userdata('anything')` is always "set".

Quick fix, assuming "index" is your login page in the same controller:

```
function isLogged()
{
    $isLogged = $this->session->userdata('isLogged');
    $isLoginPage = $this->router->method === 'index';

    if ( ! $isLogged && ! $isLoginPage)
    {
        redirect('login/index');
    }
}
```

Also, make sure to redirect somewhere else *from* your login page if the user *is* logged in.